# How can I remove spacing between my two ImageViews

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Lets say I am making News layout in my application. First ImageView should be the main one and thats why its bigger and other news will be presented by smaller ImageView.

So each news item has Image and Title and in the end it should look like picture below:[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koSxD.png).

But when I add images and titles (for main and secondary news) to firebase I get spacing between news. How can I remove the spacing? [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5YF.jpg)

```
<!-- news_item.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- Main News -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newsImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/newsTitle"/>

    <!-- Secondary News -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsImageSecondary"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newsTitleSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTitleSecondary"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/newsImageSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<!-- fragment_news -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/transferToolbarNews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="News"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- RecyclerView for News -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/transferToolbarNews" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Here is my NewsAdapter

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

```
private Context context;
private List<NewsItem> newsList;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<NewsItem> newsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
    return new NewsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NewsItem newsItem = newsList.get(position);
    holder.bind(newsItem);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}

static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView newsImage;
    private TextView newsTitle;
    private ImageView newsImageSecondary;
    private TextView newsTitleSecondary;

    public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        newsImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
        newsTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
        newsImageSecondary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImageSecondary);
        newsTitleSecondary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleSecondary);
    }

    public void bind(NewsItem newsItem) {
        
        Glide.with(itemView)
                .load(newsItem.getImageUrl())
                .into(newsImage);
        newsTitle.setText(newsItem.getTitle());

        
        Glide.with(itemView)
                .load(newsItem.getImageUrlSecondary())
                .into(newsImageSecondary);
        newsTitleSecondary.setText(newsItem.getTitleSecondary());
    }
}
```

}

I tried to make News layout that will have Main News and Secondary News.
Main News should be at the top and secondary news below main one.
Result is that I get one below another one but with huge spacing between them.

Comment: I have reviewed your XML, and it appears to be fine. However, could you please share your adapter code? There might be some issues related to spacing in your code that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, I added the News Adapter so you can take I look.

Comment: I reviewed your XML and adapter class as well and  which looks fine.   There might be  some issue with your Images. You should try to debug this with hardcoded image from the drawable to make sure that your layout is showing the Images fine or not then you can confirm that either there is issue in xml or your images coming from the  server.

Comment: try to place `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your ImageView.